# How to make this Mouse Cursor Script work in Blender 2.74? (BGE)

Tags: python, game-engine

It seems that now I upgraded to Blender 2.74 this Mouse Cursor script no longer works.  I do not know Python but I think that there would be only little changes to be done.  Thanks!

```
from bge import logic
controller = logic.getCurrentController()
own = controller.owner

mouse = controller.sensors['mouse']

hitPosition = mouse.hitPosition

own.worldPosition.x = hitPosition.x
own.worldPosition.y = hitPosition.y
```

Comment: What is the error in the "System Console"? 
And also what do you hope to achieve with this script? 
I run it with no problems. I used it on a cube with a mouse over sensor,and everytime I went the cursor over the cube, the cube changed position.

Comment: I am trying to get it so you can move a png as the cursor.  I can't get it to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
This works for me. I changed it as little as possible. The red plane called "png" is the plane of your cursor. In the ground plane I put a mouse-over sensor called "mouse". I also activated true pulse trigger so that the script will run constantly when your cursor is over something.

Comment: It's still not working. I've also found another similar script but I have the same problem:the mouse looks frozen in play mode. Does anyone have any tips or hints about this issue?